# How can I prevent the query string from getting trailed to the end of the URL with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the below htaccess:

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(pageA|pageB|pageC|pageD)(?:\/(\d+)\/?(.*))?$ 
            ./$1/?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

The below URLs work properly since in the folder hierarchy, the folder names are (pageA,pageB....) and each has an `index.php` file within it and am handling the id passed in the URL to view the proper content on the page:

> www.domain.com/pageA/
>
> www.domain.com/pageA/12/title-of-item-number-12

My problem occurs when I access the folder name only and remove the trailing slash:

> www.domain.com/pageA

The requested page properly loads but the query string will be appended to the url as follows:

> www.domain.com/pageA/?var1=pageA&var2=&var3=

**How can I prevent the query string from getting trailed to the end of the URL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add another rewrite rule that only matches pageA/pageB etc. and have it rewrite to the URL without the querystring. So you'll end up with something like this:

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(pageA|pageB|pageC|pageD)$ ./$1/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(pageA|pageB|pageC|pageD)(?:\/(\d+)\/?(.*))?$ 
            ./$1/?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: simpler than I thought about it..THanks